# How to 'normalize' an array of objects?

Tags: algorithm, text-processing

I am not sure if the term 'normalization' is correct in my case, so I would appreciate if you point me at the right one. I found this term in DOM node method called [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize), which is doing kinda the same.

I am working on text processing algorithm and I need to transform this:

```
{
    type: 'bold',
    data: [
        {
            type: 'italic',
            data: 'italic text'
        },
        {
            type: 'italic',
            data: ' another italic'
        }
    ]
},
{
    type: 'italic',
    data: [
        {
            type: 'bold',
            data: 'bold text'
        },
        {
            type: 'bold',
            data: ' another bold'
        }
    ]
}
```

Into this:

```
{
    type: 'bold',
    data: [
        {
            type: 'italic',
            data: 'italic text another italic. bold text another bold'
        }
    ]
}
```

The simplest task here is to just merge neighbouring nodes with same types, but I will end up with this:

```
{
    type: 'bold',
    data: [
        {
            type: 'italic',
            data: 'italic text another italic. '
        },
    ]
},
{
    type: 'italic',
    data: [
        {
            type: 'bold',
            data: 'bold text another bold'
        },
    ]
},
```

But the output is clearly excessive. What algorithms/data structures could I use to solve my problem? Also, text processing is really hard task and I will be glad to know if there are resources on this topic and/or specific approaches/best practises. I am doing this just as a pet project of mine to improve my coding and engineering skills, so no need to recommend use or steal open source solutions :)

Comment: The logic of the algorithm you're after escapes me. The rules by which the given input is supposed to be transformed into the expected output are unclear.

Comment: In addition to merging the text, you are also transforming the sibling node into a child node. You will need two separate operations for this.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it's all about merging object with the same type into one if they are neighbours. The problem is the order of nesting is unknown and there may be cases like I provided: bold contains italic, then italic contains bold, but they clearly could be merged into one node

Comment: And are all the types you're working with types where the order of nesting is irrelevant? Or does that only apply to a subset of those types? It's pretty trivial to hack something together that transforms this specific input into the desired output, but to come up with a generic algorithm, you'll have to clarify the rules that govern the structure of your input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively merge neighbouring nodes with the same types. Here's the function you can use.
nodes => Your Array of object

```
function normalizeNodes(nodes) {
      if (!Array.isArray(nodes) || nodes.length === 0) {
        return nodes;
      }
    
      const result = [];
      let currentType = nodes[0].type;
      let currentData = [nodes[0].data];
    
      for (let i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].type === currentType) {
          currentData.push(nodes[i].data);
        } else {
          result.push({
            type: currentType,
            data: currentData.join(' ')
          });
    
          currentType = nodes[i].type;
          currentData = [nodes[i].data];
        }
      }
    
      result.push({
        type: currentType,
        data: currentData.join(' ')
      });
    
      return result;
    }
```